# Deletion of Row in TPL file of sugarCRM

Tags: jquery, sugarcrm

I am trying to delete a row in the tpl file . When user click on a particular record then that record should be deleted. In java script function

```
 var temp=button.id;
 var idTemp1 = temp.split("_");
 var rowNo =  idTemp1[1];
 var row = document.getElementById('table_row_'+rowNo); 
 row.parentNode.removeChild(rowNo);
```

I am getting rowNo but when try to get row through `document.getElementById('table_row_'+rowNo);`  getting null.
i am new to sugar. Kindly if you have solution please provide it 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know anything about sugarCRM but I'm thinking what you are trying to delete is a row in a HTML table right?  For document.getElementById('table_row_'+rowNo) to work, you have to ensure that the ID exists on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the button is a "Delete" button that exists on every single row.  Am I correct?  Why don't you try using jQuery?

If the ID of the button is something like "delete_8":

```
$('#delete_8').click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    $target.closest('tr[id^=table_row]').remove();
})
```

What this essentially does is that it binds the click event on the button.  It sets the "target" clicked element to be $target variable.  From the variable, you find the closest parent node that is a TR (I'm assuming its a table row) with an id that starts with "table_row" and remove it.

You should ultimately switch to using event delegation to handle the listening of click events on all buttons in the table instead of attaching the click event to every button in that table.

Comment: Hi Nisar, I understand you are new to StackOverflow.  Please accept this answer if it helped you.